# App hangs if the content of a UITextField password field exceeds a certain length

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8, ios10

#### Situation

I have an app that has a sign in screen with username and password.

If I enter a 12+ character password, the app freezes while I type the 12th character and the UI becomes completely unresponsive. On the screenshot you see the password screen at the 11th character. After that  the UI freezes.

I then changed the password in my backend and I can continue the workflow with the 8-character password without any problems.

This problem seems to have arisen after upgrading to Xcode8 and the iOS SDK 10.

#### Debugging

My threads looks like this and it does not seem that there is anything going on that would block the UI.

And the console does not show anything suspicious either.

[image: threads]

I can reproduce this problem both in the simulator as well as on a physical device.

#### Screenshot

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Internal id `SI#83`

Comment: Do you think that you need to add some code snippets?

Comment: The fact that CPU is at 52% while seemingly idle suggests there is something going on. Trying profiling in Instruments to see what's causing the CPU spike.

Answer (score 1):

Unchecking "Adjust to fit" from textfield will solve the problem. But its just a workaround as this is a known bug.